# Need suggestion/approach on designing push based queuing system

Tags: c#, queue, push-notification

I have a webform which has certain fields with values displayed on it. These fields are editable. There is a list of things that needs to be updated (which are time consuming) following the edits: 
1. all the edited values has to be entered into database
2. There is a scheuler which picks these values and run cetain modules

So when edits are made in quick succession, we cant go ahead and perform these updates. Before we enter The values into the database, we ll see if two edits are made for the same field. If so we ll pick only the latest edit and enter into the db.So the edited values has to be periodically picked (must be configurable) so that we can avoid running the expensive updates twice.

I am planning it to design it using a push notification and queue. That is whenever an edit is made it will be pushed into the queue. This queue will be periodically checked to get the updates and finally data is pushed into the database.Is there any other better way of doing this? Sorry for the lengthy explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you need something like nservicebus

http://particular.net/nservicebus

You can get further information about what service bus does here:

[What is a servicebus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617166/what-is-a-servicebus)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider perhaps looking into SignalR which allows bi-directional communication between the client and the server. It sounds like you have quite a lot of process "kicking off" and you may be able to better orchestrate it using SignalR to push/pull info to and from the server as necessary - just something worth considering that might help!.